# Custom event handling in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, nstableview

I need to call a block on [cmd+double-click] event from NSTableView. I know about the **-setDoubleAction:** API to set the selector for the double-click event & **-keyDown:** delegate method for handling key press events.

What I need is kind of a combination of these 2 in a single customised event handler. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Is there any way to register for such a custom event setting a callback selector?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if that is good enough for you, but I'd declare a BOOL property, which I set to 'YES' at the keyDown event for the desired key and set to 'NO' at the keyUp event.
In the action for the double click event I'd check the BOOL property, if it's 'YES' -> do the thing otherwise return.

Comment: Yes thats one way of doing it for sure. This is a last resort in my list right now. A more subtle combined event handling way is what I am looking for ... one delegate callback rather than 2. In any case, did you try this out in any practical scenario? Do you see any anomalies or lagging?

Comment: I wrote a wrapper to get around the combined event handling. Using the following callback: **-(void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent**, I am able to check whether the concerned key is pressed/released & set a private flag based on that. Then in **-setDoubleAction:**, I am checking if the key is pressed & invoke the concerned method which I had to on [cmd+double-click].